# nvim (plugged with coc, coc-clangd) is showing parameters for every function. How do disable it?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, plugin

my nvim (plugged with coc + coc-clangd) is showing the paramters for every function, how do I disable it ?

I'm using a common vimrc for vim and neovim, but this problem only happens in neovim.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;

fp = fopen(fname, "wb"); ‣filename: fname ‣modes: "wb"
if (!fp)
{
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 7):

I propose you set:

```
{
  "inlayHint.enable": false
}
```

in your `coc-settings.json`. You can get to this config by running the command `:CocConfig` in a vim/neovim buffer. See [doc](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd/issues/512).

Comment: thanks a lot. This did work. Any idea why clangd.inlayHints.enable otoh does not?

Comment: https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd/commit/b1d4e166bc742cf826bd54b53e22e7c193a1d299

Comment: I see, thank you